# Is the tensor product structure $\hat{H}_0 = \hat{h}_0 \otimes \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{I} \otimes \hat{h}_0$ wrong when interactions are included?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, interactions

First, consider two **uncoupled** harmonic oscillators $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ with classical Lagrangian
$$
L_0 = \frac{1}{2} m_1 \dot{x}_1^2 -  \frac{1}{2} m_1 \omega_1^2 x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 \dot{x}_2^2 -  \frac{1}{2} m_2 \omega_2^2 x_2^2
$$
where $m_j$ and $\omega_j$ are respectively the masses and frequencies for each respective oscillator.

Then we quantize this system: determine the conjugate momenta $p_j(t) = \frac{\delta L_0}{\delta \dot{x}_j} = m_j\dot{x}_j(t)$, take the Legendre transform $H_0 = \dot{x}_j p_j - L_0$, and think of the variables as operators $\hat{x}_j$ and $\hat{p}_j$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. (and impose $[\hat{x}_1, \hat{p}_1] = i \mathbb{I}$ and so on)

This must mean that the overall Hilbert space for the combined system is $L_2(\mathbb{R}) \otimes L_2(\mathbb{R})$, and the Hamiltonian operator must be
$$
\hat{H}_0 = \left( \frac{1}{2m_1} \hat{p}_1^2 -  \frac{1}{2} m_1 \omega_1^2 \hat{x}_1^2 \right) \otimes \mathbb{I} +  \mathbb{I} \otimes \left( \frac{1}{2m_1} \hat{p}_2^2 -  \frac{1}{2} m_2 \omega_2^2 \hat{x}_2^2 \right)
$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity on $L_2(\mathbb{R})$. From there the energy eigenspectrum is $\{ | n_1 \rangle \otimes | n_2 \rangle \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset L_2(\mathbb{R}) \otimes L_2(\mathbb{R})$, where $| n_j \rangle$ are the usual harmonic oscillator eigenstates on $L_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Next, suppose we couple the systems through the interaction
$$
L = L_0 - \lambda u(t) x_1(t) x_2(t)
$$
where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function, which turns on the interaction at $t=0$ (and $\lambda$ is some coupling). My guess is then that the Hamiltonian operator for the system should now be
$$
\hat{H}(t) =  \left( \frac{1}{2m_1} \hat{p}_1(t)^2 -  \frac{1}{2} m_1 \omega_1^2 \hat{x}_1(t)^2 \right) \otimes \mathbb{I} +  \mathbb{I} \otimes \left( \frac{1}{2m_1} \hat{p}_2(t)^2 -  \frac{1}{2} m_2 \omega_2^2 \hat{x}_2(t)^2 \right) + \lambda u(t) \hat{x}_1(t) \otimes \hat{x}_2(t) \tag{1}
$$
where I have snuck in time-dependance of the operators (maybe this is wrong?), where I think that the time-dependence of the operators is given by operators like
$$
\hat{x}_1(t) \otimes \mathbb{I} \to \hat{U}(t,0)^{\dagger} \big( \hat{x}_1(0) \otimes \mathbb{I} \big) \hat{U}(t,0) \tag{2}
$$
with the evolution operator
$$
\hat{U}(t,t') = \mathcal{T}\exp\left( - i \int_{t'}^t ds \ \hat{H}(t) \right) \ .
$$

It looks like the time evolution operator is some complicated operator on $L_2(\mathbb{R} ) \otimes L_2(\mathbb{R})$, and therefore by no means you should get a clean tensor product structure of this operator (*ie.* like $\hat{U} = \hat{U}_1 \otimes \hat{U}_2$). This then implies that you do **NOT** get a structure given by equation (2) (*ie.*  $\hat{U}(t,0)^{\dagger} \big( \hat{x}_1(0) \otimes \mathbb{I} \big) \hat{U}(t,0) \neq x_1(t) \otimes \mathbb{I}$). Because of this, it seems that the free Hamiltonian ($\hat{H}_0$) part of the Hamiltonian in (1) cannot possibly be correct (*ie.* it can't have the structure $\hat{h}_0 \otimes \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{I} \otimes \hat{h}_0$ as I have written in (1), since it is composed of operators $\hat{x}_1(t)^2$ and so on).

**My Question:** Is the tensor product structure $\hat{H}_0 = \hat{h}_0 \otimes \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{I} \otimes \hat{h}_0$ of the free Hamiltonian wrong when we include an interaction? For the specific choice of interaction here, it should be true that the tensor product structure should be correct for $t<0$.

EDIT: What is the correct Hamiltonian for $t>0$?

Comment: I feel like the only answer I can give is "Yes.", because you explained the reasons perfectly well.

Comment: I don't see your point. What is the problem/question? Of course, such an evolution will not preserve the tensor product structure of states & operators. But this does not mean there isn't a natural tensor product structure on the space.

Comment: @Norbert_Schuch I am not debating that the space has a natural tensor product structure, rather I am confused what the Hamiltonian should actually be? What is the correct hamiltonian for this system for $t>0$?

Comment: Another issue that comes up as a result of my argument, is that the interaction $\hat{x}_1(t) \otimes \hat{x}_2(t)$ can't be right for $t>0$.

Comment: This depends on whether you work in the Heisenberg or Schrödinger picture ...

Comment: Shouldn't the Hamiltonian be the same in the Heisenberg and Schr$\ddot{\mathrm{o}}$dinger pictures?

Comment: No, that's exactly the point, isn't it?  In the Schrödinger picture, the Hamiltonian is time-independent.  -- Also, you need to use @[username] otherwise I don't get notified.

Comment: @Norbert_Schuch I think this is the source of my confusion: I did not realize that the $H_\mathrm{S}(t) \neq H_{\mathrm{H}}(t)$ in general. Is it true then that in my equation (1) I wrote down the Schrodinger-picture Hamiltonian (and so there should be no $t$'s on the $x_j$'s and $p_j$'s?). And then the Heisenberg picture Hamiltonian is $H_{\mathrm{H}}(t) = U(t,0)^\dagger H(t) U(t,0)$, and then of course in this case the tensor product structure of the ``free part'' must be ruined.

Comment: @QuantumEyedea Mistyping my username will prevent me from being ping-ed!  (SE offers an autocomplete. Spaces should be omitted. Or you just stop after 4 (?) letters.)

Comment: ... sounds right.